# How can I get text from html fragment in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

all
Here is some html string I got from website by ajax request

```
{ 
  "data":{
          label: 'description',
          values:  ['<p class="description">'
                'someting'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                '<b>mytitle_1</b>'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                'something_1'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                '<b>mytitle_2</b>'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                'something_2'
            '</p>']}
    }
```

the value of the values key is html fragment, how can I get the all text inside the data["values"].
I'm using scrapy and is there any way to parse it by scrapy response get method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to extract the html content, cast it as a scrapy selector and use `xpath('//text()').getall()` on it.

Example:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

resp_json = {
  "data":{
          'label': 'description',
          'values':  ['<p class="description">'
                'someting'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                '<b>mytitle_1</b>'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                'something_1'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                '<b>mytitle_2</b>'
                '<br>'
                '<br>'
                'something_2'
            '</p>']}
    }

a = Selector(text=resp_json['data']['values'][0], type='html')
content = a.xpath('//text()').getall()
print(content)
```

Output:

```
['someting', 'mytitle_1', 'something_1', 'mytitle_2', 'something_2']
```